# Python Regex \pL matching issues

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a list of keywords I have, taking care to include all Latin characters (e.g accented).

Here's an example

```
import regex as re
p = r'((?!\pL)|^)blah((?!\pL)|$)'
print(re.search(p, "blah u"))
print(re.search(p, "blahé u"))
print(re.search(p, "éblah u"))
print(re.search(p, "blahaha"))
```

gives:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='blah'>
None
None
None
```

Which looks correct. However:

```
print(re.search(p, "u blah"))
```

gives:

```
None
```

This is wrong, as I expect a match for "u blah".

I've tried to also use Pythons built in `re` module, but I cannot get it to work with `\pL` or `\p{Latin}` due to "bad-escape" errors. I've also tried to use unicode strings (without the "r") but despite adding slashes to `\\\\pL`, I just can't get this to work right.

Note: I'm using Python 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your `((?!\pL)|^)blah((?!\pL)|$)` regex is that the `((?!\pL)|^)` group contains two alternatives where the first one always fails the regex (why? Because `(?!\pL)` is a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if the next char is a letter, and the next char to match is `b` in `blah`) and only `^` works all the time, i.e. your regex is equal to `^blah((?!\pL)|$)` and only matches at the start of string.

Note `(?!\pL)` already matches a position at the end of string, so `((?!\pL)|$)` = `(?!\pL)`.

You should use

```py
(?<!\pL)blah(?!\pL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SzkDwk/1) (switched to PCRE for the demo purposes).

Note that the `re`-compatible version of the regex is

```py
(?<![^\W\d_])blah(?![^\W\d_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SzkDwk/2).

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer!